Spotify User Authorization forbidden error
I'm creating a project using spotify API and springboot but having some issues with user authorization.
Problem: I can authorize but only once, after that I have to wait 3600s to auth with same account or even a different account which is a huge issue. I looked up online but couldn't find any working solution. I was wondering if anyone can help me solve this issue or even give some advice on how I should proceed with this, I would really appreciate that.
I'm following this repo:
github.com/spotify-web-api-java
 @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> spotifyLogin() {
        try {
            String state = generateRandomString(16);

            stateStore.put(state, "pending");

            SpotifyApi spotifyApi = spotifyConfiguration.getSpotifyObject();
            AuthorizationCodeUriRequest authorizationCodeUriRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCodeUri()
                    .scope("user-library-read user-top-read")
                    .state(state)
                    .show_dialog(true)
                    .build();

            URI uri = authorizationCodeUriRequest.execute();
            Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("spotifyAuthUrl", uri.toString());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body(Map.of("error", "Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

 @GetMapping("/callback")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getSpotifyUserCode(
            @RequestParam("code") String userCode,
            @RequestParam("state") String state) throws IOException, ParseException, SpotifyWebApiException {
        try {
            SpotifyApi spotifyApi = spotifyConfiguration.getSpotifyObject();

            AuthorizationCodeRequest authorizationCodeRequest = spotifyApi.authorizationCode(userCode).build();
            AuthorizationCodeCredentials authorizationCode = authorizationCodeRequest.execute();

            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(authorizationCode.getAccessToken());
            spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(authorizationCode.getRefreshToken());

            GetCurrentUsersProfileRequest getCurrentUsersProfile = spotifyApi.getCurrentUsersProfile().build();
            User user = getCurrentUsersProfile.execute();

            if (userProfileService.userExists(user.getId())) {
                if (userProfileService.isTokenExpired(user.getId())) {
                    spotifyApi = refreshAccessToken(userProfileService.getRefreshToken(user.getId()), user.getId());
                }
            }

            userProfileService.InsertOrUpdateUserDetails(user, spotifyApi.getAccessToken(), spotifyApi.getRefreshToken());

            Map<String, Object> responseData = new HashMap<>();
            responseData.put("userId", user.getId());
            responseData.put("username", user.getDisplayName());
            responseData.put("email", user.getEmail());
            responseData.put("accessToken", spotifyApi.getAccessToken());
            responseData.put("refreshToken", spotifyApi.getRefreshToken());
            responseData.put("country", user.getCountry());
            responseData.put("displayName", user.getDisplayName());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(responseData);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Map<String, Object> errorResponse = new HashMap<>();
            errorResponse.put("error", "Error processing Spotify user code: " + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(errorResponse);
        }
    }

I tried adding randomly generated state for each user and updating the access token using my refresh token expecting it to work properly but It didn't really do anything.
FIRST ATTEMPT:
1st API call: /api/login
response: redirectURI/code="" (working as expected)
2nd api call: /api/callback?code=val1&state=val2
response: correctly returns a JSON with user details including access/refresh tokens
SECOND ATTEMPT:
1st API call: /api/login
response: redirectURI/code="" (working as expected)
2nd api call: /api/callback?code=val1&state=val2
response:
{
"error": "Error processing Spotify user code: Forbidden"
}

PS: After 3600s (code expiration) it works again only once and repeats this pattern.

which of the 2 methods has the issue? Please post the error message / logs

I just added this on my post. Please check again, thankyou

Are you using the same client_id and client_secret? If that is the case then seems to me this is not a bug but a feature as in expected behavior. The same client can only request one access_token at a time which then expires in 3600 seconds after what you can request a new one

Thankyou for your response, yes spotify only provides with a single client_id and client secret per app, to have multiple of these I'll have to switch between the apps which is not practical.
There are similar websites like https://playlistable.io/ with over 50k users that seem to handle the auth just fine. How do you think I should proceed with this now?

I think you mixing your app's authentication and authorization with Spotify's API authentication and Authorization. Your application should handle its own user's authentication without depending on Spotify.
Your App is a Spotify client, hence it must have a client id and secret. With that you have to get your access code and refresh code. Later you should renew your access code using the refresh code. It is the basic OAuth flow which is standard.
From the code, I can make out that you are trying to create user in Spotify. Why do you have to do that? If you can elaborate your usecase, probably I can help better.

I was trying to get account information of each user that logs into the app using spotify auth so I can generate tracks & playlists for them in their own spotify library.
According to the doc (link) this seemed like the correct flow.
The first API call correctly returns the user information, a refresh token with 1 hour epiration time and correctly adds my app in their spotify account. During this 1 hour as you mentioned I can't get any new logins.
Can you elaborate your part a bit more so I can make it work?

Before using the access token you have to check if it has expired. You can get the expiry date from the token. If it has expired you need to rrquest for a new one with the help of a refresh token. If access token is still valid invoke the other APIs

I suggest that you take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to better understand how SO works. Also learn about privileges.
